# Hold state on autocomplete when switching between pages

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is there a way for jquery autocomplete to hold state of the suggestions in the menu when a user start typing and the menu of suggestions shows up he decides to look on another webpage in another tab of the browser? That is, I what to be able to hold the suggestions in the autocomplete so that the suggestions is there when the user returns from the temporarily visited tab.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is set a session cookie for that info, and add an update to the cookie every time the autocomplete updates:

Here's also a great cookie plugin to use in jquery, although for speed, straight-up javascript would probably be slightly faster:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie